# How can I add separators to lists of numbers?

Tags: python, list, separator

I'm having an exercise where it told me to print out each person's favourite numbers. When it came to people with more than one number, I couldn't keep the numbers in one line, separated by commas. Can you suggest a solution?

My code

```
favourite_numbers = {
    "ha": [20, 10, 4],
    "quynh": [2, 5],
    "nhung": [3, 10, 12],
    "giang": [10],
}

for name, numbers in favourite_numbers.items():
    if len(numbers) == 1:
        for number in numbers:
            print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite number is {number}.")
    elif len(numbers) >= 2:
        print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite numbers are:")
        for number in numbers:
            print(f"{number}")
```

The output for a person with multiple numbers looks like this

```
Ha's favourite numbers are:
20
10
4
```

I was expecting it to be like this:

```
Ha's favourite numbers are: 20, 10, 4
```

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using two calls to print() when there is more than one number in the value list. In the second call to print() just unpack the list:

```
favourite_numbers = {
    "ha": [20, 10, 4],
    "quynh": [2, 5],
    "nhung": [3, 10, 12],
    "giang": [10],
}

for k, v in favourite_numbers.items():
    s = 's are' if len(v) > 1 else ' is'
    print(f"{k.title()}'s favourite number{s} ", end='')
    print(*v, sep=', ')
```

Optionally use map/join as follows:

```
for k, v in favourite_numbers.items():
    s = 's are' if len(v) > 1 else ' is'
    print(f"{k.title()}'s favourite number{s}", ', '.join(map(str, v)))
```

**Output:**

```
Ha's favourite numbers are 20, 10, 4
Quynh's favourite numbers are 2, 5
Nhung's favourite numbers are 3, 10, 12
Giang's favourite number is 10
```

Comment: Thank you @DarkKnight. Can you please explain how that *v in the last print() works?

Comment: I refer you to PEP 3132: https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/

Answer (score 1):

[Python String join() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) seems like it would be helpful.

```py
favourite_numbers = {
    "ha": [20, 10, 4],
    "quynh": [2, 5],
    "nhung": [3, 10, 12],
    "giang": [10],
}

for name, numbers in favourite_numbers.items():
    if len(numbers) == 1: length = 'number is'
    elif len(numbers) > 1: length = 'numbers are'
    numbers = ', '.join(map(str, numbers))
    print(f"\n{name.title()}'s favourite {length}", numbers)
```

output:

```
Ha's favourite numbers are 20, 10, 4

Quynh's favourite numbers are 2, 5

Nhung's favourite numbers are 3, 10, 12

Giang's favourite number is 10
```

Answer (score -1):

```
favourite_numbers = {
    "ha": [20, 10, 4],
    "quynh": [2, 5],
    "nhung": [3, 10, 12],
    "giang": [10]
}

for name in favourite_numbers:
    numbers_in_line = ""
    i = 1
    count = len(favourite_numbers[name])
    for number in favourite_numbers[name]:
        if i == count:
            comma = ""
            numbers_in_line += str(number) + comma
        else:
            comma = ", "
            numbers_in_line += str(number) + comma
        i += 1
    print(f"{name}'s favourite numbers are: {numbers_in_line}")
```

The output will be like that:

```
ha's favourite numbers are: 20, 10, 4
quynh's favourite numbers are: 2, 5
nhung's favourite numbers are: 3, 10, 12
giang's favourite numbers are: 10
```

Here is a print screen for the code after it was executed at PyCharm:

[image]

Comment: Your code does **not** produce that output

Comment: It does, I checked it again twice, you just need to make sure the indentation is right, and the print occurs at the end of the first loop. I will add a print screen, to show the result.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Actually, the output you got isn't really what I wanted. There is one person who has only 1 favorite number, so the output should be "Giang's favourite number is" and not "[...] numbers are".

Comment: @YasserKhalil Your original answer did not produce the required output. Your current version does work albeit in a remarkably inefficient manner